# Get attribute of all items in container python

Tags: python

I have the following (obviously simplified) class

```
class A(object)
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = 'b'
        # Other class attributes are added


class B(list):
    """
    Some customization of this class...
    """
    pass

BB = B([A(i) for i in range(10)])
```

I want to do

```
B.a
```

and get a list of all the `a` attributes from every contained item in `B`. I know in order to do this, I need to overwrite `__getattr__`, but I'm not sure the best way to implement this. This needs to be generic as `B` doesn't know any of the attributes of `A` that may need to be accessed.

Can someone offer some advice on the implementation of this idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## General Solution:

If you wish for this to work across the board, then  you can override `__getattr__()` as you thought:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = a-1

class B(list):
    """
    Some customization of this class...
    """
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return (getattr(item, name) for item in self)

bb = B([A(i) for i in range(10)])
print(list(bb.a))
print(list(bb.b))
```

Giving us:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Note that `__getattr__()` only gets called if the attribute doesn't already exist. So, if you set `bb.b` to another value, you will get that instead:

```
bb = B([A(i) for i in range(10)])
bb.b = 5
print(list(bb.a))
print(bb.b)
```

Gives us:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
5
```

Example to show the lack of need for `B` to know about it's contents:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> b = B([datetime.date(2012, 1, 1), datetime.date(2012, 2, 2), datetime.date(2012, 3, 3)])
>>> list(b.month)
[1, 2, 3]
```

## Original Answer:

The easiest way to do this is with a [generator expression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY).

```
class B(list):
    """
    Some customization of this class...
    """
@property
def a(self):
    return (item.a for item in self)
```

This generator expression is the equivalent of:

```
@property
def a(self):
    for item in self:
        yield item.a
```

I also used [the `property()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) as a decorator to make `B.a` act as an attribute rather than a function.

We can then do:

```
bb = B([A(i) for i in range(10)])
print(list(bb.a))
```

and get:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You could use a list comprehension ([item.a for item in self]) if you definitely wanted a list rather than an iterator, but generally the iterator is more useful, and can be easily made into a list (as shown above).

Note you could also do this even more simply by assigning the generator expression:

```
class B(list):
        """
        Some customization of this class...
        """
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(B, self).__init__(*args)
        self.a = (item.a for item in self)
```

However, this means the generator will be exhausted after the first use, so I would advise against it.

Comment: This is a good idea (I've never used the property decorator before). The problem is that the attribute of A is not always 'a'. (I failed to mention that in my original question.) Can I make this more generic for any attribute name of A?

Comment: @Lattywire That requires that `B` knows about `A` (which it doesn't).

Comment: @Jeremy Why does it require ``B`` knowing anything about ``A``?

Comment: @Lattywire, because you have to pass the attributes of `A` to `B`'s constructor as part of the `args`. I guess `B` doesn't have to know about `A`, but the programmer has to know everything of `A` that will be accessed through `B`.

Comment: @Jeremy: I think you are looking at the wrong part of my answer, the new bit is at the top. Edit: I added an example.

Comment: @Lattywire You are right, I missed what was at the top as I thought your update was on the bottom. Sorry about that. The new stuff on the top does the trick.